# Antd Using <Table> as Array Form Input

Tags: antd

i currently building a react app with ant-design UI. I have a problem regarding form. So far, i already able to create and submit normal form. But as i tried to create a more complex form, i faced these problem:

I want to create a form with input like this:

```
code: string,
name: string,
order: {
 itemid: number,
 qty: number
}
```

the 'order' part is an array, which means i can have more than 1 order in one form. I want to create that part of the form by using  component in antd, where i can render the column like this:

```
{ title: L('Item Id'), width: 150, render: (text: string, item: any, index: any) => (
                <Form.Item {...formItemLayout}>
                    {getFieldDecorator('order[' + index + '].itemid', {
                        rules: [{
                            required: true, message: 'Please select id!'
                        }]
                    })(
                        <ItemIdSelectInput/>
                    )}
                </Form.Item>
            )  }
```

Can i use the table like that?

Also, as far as i know,  component must have a 'datasource' in order to be used, while i want to create a 'Create' form where has no initial value (empty). Is there any reference or a better way to create this kind of form in antd? Thanks in advance!